# count query filter

Tags: oracle, select, filtering, aggregate-functions

I want to filter counted query result.

```
select count(distinct tmr_id) AS Count ,CONTRACTID from status_handling
```

This query return 2 columns like:

Count ContractID

```
1    23344
2    28344
2    34343
2    29344
1    26344
```

I just filter 2 (Count) values. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle we have to use GROUP BY with aggregate functions.  When we want to filter by the aggregated result there is the HAVING clause:

```
select count(distinct tmr_id) ,CONTRACT_ID 
from status_handling
group by CONTRACT_ID 
having count(distinct tmr_id) = 2
/
```